# Java type inference fails during compile-time, but Eclipse compiles and runs just fine

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, type-inference

I'm having a hard time to understand why the following code does not compile in Java 8 / 9, but it works just fine if I do a "Run" from within Eclipse IDE:

```
package de.playground.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class InferenceTest {

    class InferenceObject<T> implements Comparable<InferenceObject<T>> {
        @Override
        public int compareTo(InferenceObject<T> o) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InferenceTest inferenceTest = new InferenceTest();
        List<InferenceObject<?>> result = inferenceTest.read();
        System.out.println(String.format("Array contains %d element(s)", result.size()));
    }

    private List<InferenceObject<?>> read() {
        List<InferenceObject<?>> simpleList = new ArrayList<>();
        InferenceObject<String> infObj = new InferenceObject<>();
        simpleList.add(infObj);
        // Collections.<InferenceObject<?>>sort(simpleList);
        Collections.sort(simpleList);
        return simpleList;
    }
}
```

`javac InferenceTest.java` produces the following error:

```
InferenceTest.java:26: error: no suitable method found for sort(List<InferenceTest.InferenceObject<?>>)
                Collections.sort(simpleList);
                           ^
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: InferenceTest.InferenceObject<?>
        upper bounds: InferenceTest.InferenceObject<CAP#1>,Comparable<? super T#1>)
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
1 error
```

The issue is that the type inference fails due to the wildcard generics used - I'm confused as to why this code compiles in Eclipse, whereas the  Oracle JDK 8 / 9 refuses to compile this code - Might it be a regression of [Bug 6468354](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6468354)?

Used environment: Kubuntu 17.10 x86_64, javac 1.8.0, javac 1.8.0_131, javac 1.8.0_151 and javac 9.0.1

Workaround:

```
class InferenceObject<T> implements Comparable<InferenceObject<?>> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(InferenceObject<?> o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to write this code without explicitly stating a type instead of the wildcard generic and without using the slightly different workaround?

Comment: Linked bug is marked as non-reproducible. And when you say "regression" do you imply that this code was compiling fine in Java 7?

Comment: Tested compilation with 1.8.0_131 windows 64, i don't have any problems

Comment: Reproduced this also with javac 1.8.0_131 and 1.8.0 in Kubuntu x86_64, code does not compile.
A regression bug means a bug introduced after it had already been fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having a hard time to understand why the following code does not
>   compile in Java 8 / 9

That code does not compile (using 1.8.0_161) because you are asking **Collections.sort()** to sort objects of a type that has not correctly implemented the Comparable interface. From the [Javadoc for Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-):

*Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements. **All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface**.*

In your initial code the members of the list to be sorted were of type `InferenceObject<?>` but the parameter to your **compareTo()** method was of type `InferenceObject<T>`, so it is correct that there was a compiler error.

The reason for the compiler error would be much clearer if the parameter to the **compareTo()** method was (say) `InferenceObject<Float>`, and the List to be sorted consisted of (say) `InferenceObject<LocalDate>` objects. The same principle applies in the initial code listing although the cause is less obvious.

Your original InferenceObject class definition would have been fine if your list contained InferenceObjects of any specific type that implemented **Comparable**. For example:

`List<InferenceObject<String>> simpleList = new ArrayList<>();`
`List<InferenceObject<BigInteger>> simpleList = new ArrayList<>();`
`List<InferenceObject<Year>> simpleList = new ArrayList<>();`

> I'm confused as to why this code compiles in Eclipse

So am I. It looks like a bug with the Eclipse compiler. You could [raise a bug report](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_report_a_bug_in_Eclipse%3F).

> What is the correct way to write this code without explicitly stating
>   a type instead of the wildcard generic

You are already doing it the correct way in your revised code. You either want to create a list of objects of type `InferenceObject<?>` (i.e. type unknown) or you want to create a list of objects of type `InferenceObject<T>`, where 'T' is some specific type. It's a binary choice.

(It's actually a bit more nuanced than that since you could have a `List<InferenceObject<? extends Number>>` but I don't think you were asking about that.)

> without using the slightly different **workaround**?

Don't think of it as a "workaround". Think of it as a pre-requisite for writing the code correctly.

But one other worthwhile change to your code would be to declare **simpleList** like this since you know you want to sort its elements:

```
List<InferenceObject<? extends Comparable>> simpleList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then the compiler will flag an error if you try to add an invalid InferenceObject to the List:

```
simpleList.add(new InferenceObject<String>()); // OK, since String implements Comparable
simpleList.add(new InferenceObject<StringBuffer>()); // Error, since StringBuffer does not implement Comparable
```